How badly did I damage board with first time soldering to remove component?

First time soldering. Is this thing unusable or might it still work?

We can't know if it will work or not. I likely did not look like that originally so it is likely beyond repair now.

What piece was there before? From the looks of the soldering pads, it must have been something huge.


How badly did I damage board with first time soldering to remove component?

Pretty bad.

The silkscreen above the damaged pads contains THUMBSTICK. Was the removed component a PCB mounted joystick?

Aye, this is a pcb to a valve index controller

You've pretty thoroughly destroyed that, I expect.

you pass the Destruction 101 course

Step away from the soldering iron.  It was not working, so in principle you could not make it worse, but to be honest, you did.  Too hot and too big a tip with no flux.  Check out local electronics colleges and take a soldering course.

Removing thumbsticks like that are difficult for even seasoned solderers if you don’t have the right equipment. There is a whole array of desoldering tools available for tasks like this.

You shouldn't practice soldering on SMD mount boards, particularly not on commercial quality (meaning low quality) PCBs that aren't usually designed to withstand multiple resoldering of parts. Play around with through-hole and panel mount components first.

Why was this question closed as opinion-based? Soldering is not subjective, technical standards that in detail mention what's acceptable for a certain quality class and what is not. There will be a corresponding IPC rule for this very question, I'm sure of it. Being too lazy to dig it up or being ignorant of the IPC standards to begin with are not valid reasons to close questions. Voting to reopen.

"Bereft of life, it rests in peace". I would not attempt to recover from that, save the most dire of circumstances.
It could be possible to trace all those tortured pads back to wherever they go, a dozen or so places, clean out and remove the dangling shards of copper that could otherwise short things, fasten the new component in with epoxy and run a dozen or so fine jumpers all over the board, but the reliability hit and time commitment would be significant. It's the sort of thing that the best techs will do in order to get something like a mobile phone to work for a few minutes so priceless data can be recovered (which I don't think is a concern here). And hours of a good tech's time don't come cheap. If the board is delaminated the damage may be hard to assess even with a good microscope and good tools.
And, certainly no insult intended, everyone starts some place, that kind of work would require considerably more skill and almost surely better equipment and supplies than has been demonstrated in the creation of the issue. If you're interested in learning, Youtuber Jason on STS Telecom demonstrates those skills to a high degree. He can dig into inner layers, create new 0201 pads out of microscopic spirals of wire, anchor them with UV-cured adhesive, add solder mask and UV cure it, etc.

Yep, if he hadn't soldered it to the board it'd be pushing up the daisies.

With the excessive amount of heat in this case I'd worry if the bond wires of the nearby IC have been fried. In which that one would have to be replaced too. Not worth the time, RIP.
